# Java data output "date" and "month"

Tags: java, input, output

I'm just looking at getting a program where the user is asked to input day and month in "int" format, say "1" for day and "1" for month will give "1 January".

Have it easy at the start as can just have 1 to 12 linked to "January" etc, but need to have a second string limiting the number of days in each month.

Also, have to have a substring to insert "st" "nd" to the final output, say if day number is "13" output will be "13th".

Have the following so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class q1 {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a month: ");
    String first = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter a day: ");
    String second = input.nextLine();       
    input.close();

    if (first.charAt(0) == '1') {
        first = "January";
    } else if (first.charAt(0) == '2') {
        first = "February";
    else if (first.charAt(0) == '3') {
        first = "March";
    {
    System.out.println("The date entered is the" second + "of " + first);}
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You appear to be asking us to do your homework for you.  We will not be doing this, as doing so would not be a benefit to anyone, and in the long term, it will actually be a net harm to you.   Please review your class notes and feel free to [edit] this question to be more specific with where you are having difficulty.  Read also: [An open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Am just stuck where to include a specific part where to limit and ask the user to input day number again, say if "32" is input and is January, would assume "else if >=31" for January would be the logic? Have "Pseudocode" done up just to limit it for this.

Answer (score 0):

For the substring which you need to append to your day, you could look at a map kind of data structure.

```
Map<Integer, String> daySubstringMap = new TreeMap<>();

{1: "st"}
{2: "nd"}
```

Or

```
Map<Set<Integer>, String> daysSubstringMap  = new HashMap<>()

{[1]: "st"}
{[2]: "nd"}
{[4,5,6,7]:"th"}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, and this can be referred to in the final output by concatenation?

Comment: You can use it as a static map & refer it when you are generating the string